# How to add a calendar widget near to each todo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ember.js

I tried to build a todo application using ember js and did it successfully,also added a common calendar.Now am trying to add a due date to each todo,but am not getting it.

**my html code is**

```
{{#each todo in model itemController="todo"}}
<li> <p align="right">  Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p></li> 
{{/each}}
```

**and my view code is**

```
didInsertElement: function() {
        this.$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(); });

Am very New to ember js,jquery. so kindly tell me where am I doing wrong.!
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Provide a fiddle link.. It will help to provide faster solutions..

Comment: You can't repeat ID's in a page. They are unique by definition

Comment: @bowdzone when ever i create a new todo, new calendar widget appears, but it appears only at the top?? i want the widget to appear near each todo

Comment: @charlietfl.. ya repeating id is the problem. how to make it render for each todo calendar. kindly help me

Comment: not really familiar with ember but i assume you may have access to DOM elements and then can do something like `$(emberElement).datepicker()`

Comment: @charlietfl I found that i should rerender method to make it work.  Where should i use the rerender method exactly??